# Creating draggable tags like linkedin, with parent div element and an svg image and text inside

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am a little new to css and angular. I just need a head start on using css to create [image]

This outer tag is basically a div element that has an image and a text inside it.

Edit: Adding some sample code as asked:

html file:

```
<div id="tag">
   <svg class="tag-img" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
       <use class="tag-img" xlink:href="./images/add-new_tags.svg" />
   </svg>
   <span class="tagText">tag 1!</span>
</div>
```

css file:

```
#tag{
border-radius: 20px;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 10px;
width: 125px;
height: 17px;
border: solid 1px #000000;
}
.tag-img{
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
```

The problem is I am not able to see the svg image and text on screen

Comment: I'd suggest posting an example of what you've tried so far and how this isn't working

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3759705/hairmot added

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `border-radius` and `padding` styles to the outer element.